# Typescript conditional types based upon a function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible in Typescript to write a conditional type based upon a function type?

We can implement conditional types based up on an object interface but was wondering if we can do the same with respect to a function type.

Something like below:

```
type func<T> = (val: any) => T
type Optional<T> = (val: any) => T | undefined

type FilterOptional<T> = T extends Optional<any> ? undefined : T

type a = FilterOptional<(val: any) => number>
// a is undefined but need it to be (val: any) => number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to return `undefined` if the return type contains `undefined`, then you may try this:

```js
type FilterOptional<T extends (...args: any) => any> = undefined extends ReturnType<T> ? undefined : T

type a = FilterOptional<(val: any) => number> // (val: any) => number
type b = FilterOptional<(val: any) => number | undefined> // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.

In fact, your code works without modification. I'll just add some examples:

```
type func<T> = (val: unknown) => T

type foo<T> = T extends func<any> ? T : undefined // some other types

// Take positive conditional branch
type A = foo<() => void> // () => void
type B = foo<(val: number) => void> // (val: number) => void

// Take negative conditional branch
type C = foo<(val: number, secondArg: string) => void> // undefined
type D = foo<number> // undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgrgOwMYB4AqA+KBeKAKANwEMAbALikQGsEB7AdwQEocs0Aod0SWW29LLjRQIAD2AQEAEwDOsRKiIIQWAPxRhFRFIgwAlgghSoAehNQZtALbRawABYQATlG4QZnMxqJVoYWjJ6wHoE0Ei00kF6EaRQAEZOSkj2XODQAII4vPx4LNhYBLR6UlheuaxQhcWpPABCWTB8KISkFAhwVnHOeQVFJabmLeRQ7Z3dFVVSnuZoPtCGAOZEwaFQ4ZHBMSTxicgpblAAwg1NQ20dXU4ANBYQ61LpTgsUMsBOBgs9lX2l5tq6BiMNWgABETvxRpdfpRpADDFIgA)

Comment: Sorry my first example didn't clear my intention. I have updated the code snippet.